# After Git Checkout files are marked deleted

Tags: windows, git

on checkout specific branch after specific branch - resulting in deleted files .
Below is out put from Git bash - no changes before checkout but files are marked as deleted .
files do exist on both

```
user@BUILDER-VS22-001 MINGW64 /c/localrepo (ver/10.0/2023/12/rel)
$ git status
On branch ver/10.0/2023/12/rel
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/ver/10.0/2023/12/rel'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

user@BUILDER-VS22-001 MINGW64 /c/localrepo (ver/10.0/2023/12/rel)
$ git checkout ver/10.0/dev
Updating files: 100% (2977/2977), done.
Switched to branch 'ver/10.0/dev'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/ver/10.0/dev'.
user@BUILDER-VS22-001 MINGW64 /c/localrepo (ver/10.0/dev)
$ git status
On branch ver/10.0/dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/ver/10.0/dev'.


Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/Z3fX.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/B1cA.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/R2dH.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/W4eJ.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/Y7kL.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/P9mN.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/D0pQ.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/S3rT.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/G6uW.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/J9vY.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/L2xA.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/O5zC.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/I8bE.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/U1dG.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/X4fI.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/C7hK.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/F0jM.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/V3lO.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/Z6nQ.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/B9pS.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/E2rU.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/H5tW.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/K8vY.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/N1xZ.h
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/Q4aB.cpp
       deleted:   x/Sources/machine/T7cD.h

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

i have tried the following without success

1. run git gc prune=now
2. test with git fsck
3. new cloned repo
4. delete local branch

the only solution i currently found is running

```
git checkout -f ver/10.0/dev twice
```

```
user@BUILDER-VS22-001 MINGW64 /c/localrepo (ver/10.0/2023/12/rel)
$ git status
On branch ver/10.0/2023/12/rel
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/ver/10.0/2023/12/rel'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

user@BUILDER-VS22-001 MINGW64 /c/localrepo (ver/10.0/2023/12/rel)
$ git checkout -f ver/10.0/dev && git checkout -f ver/10.0/dev
Updating files: 100% (2985/2985), done.
Switched to branch 'ver/10.0/dev'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/ver/10.0/dev'.
Already on 'ver/10.0/dev'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/ver/10.0/dev'.

user@BUILDER-VS22-001 MINGW64 /c/localrepo (ver/10.0/dev)
$ git status
On branch ver/10.0/dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/ver/10.0/dev'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**Found The cause:**

After the suggested case-insensitive FS i have found the following:
[image]

apparently someone has created a pull request with wrong case. and using the pull request - resolve conflicts on azure devops services caused the wrong folder case to be incorporated.
while checking out on windows it is marked as deleted.

the only way to remove this problem was to delete the folder from the web portal of azure and find all the branches which include this commit and deleted them - revert did not help.

this can be closed now.

Comment: Could it be because you are using a case-insensitive FS? Have those files been renamed (specially, changing casing)?